# How do I use an arraylist created in another method

Tags: java, arraylist, return-value

I right now made an arraylist and returned it just like in a void
Right now I got something like this I know I have to change the static void t something else to return it but I lost that version of the code.

```
package Spel;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import Tools.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


Public Class Surrounding{

 public String a;

 public static void main(String[] args) { // this just selects different specific words to put into an arraylist
        File f = new File("words.txt");
        try (FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
             BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr)) {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            String line = br.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                if (line.length() == 4) {
                    list.add(line);
                }
                line = br.readLine();
            }
            System.out.println(list);
        }
        catch (IOException xIo) {
            xIo.printStackTrace();
        }

    public void otherstuff(){
    list.get(6)
    // here I want to do some stuff with some values out of the arraylist
    }
    
}
```

What do I do to use the filled list from the one void to the other? The problem is not the ArrayList filling or any mistakes I make in the declaring of the ArrayList just how to use the returned list

Comment: "Right now I got something like this" - rather than pseudo-code, it would be really helpful if you could post *actual* code that's as close as possible to what you're trying to do. That will give us a better sense of the requirements than pseudo-code does.

Comment: how about assigning the returned list to some class field or variable so you could use it? What your code is doing right now is the equivalent of you saying "i have a list!", "where?", "i don't know, its there *somewhere*"

Comment: I have edited it to contain some actual code in my  current version I got it returning from the static void but I am not sure how to then use it in the other void again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either define your list as static member or non-static member & access it within different class methods something like:

```
public class Test {

    static List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        list.add("aa");
        list.add("bb");
        list.add("cc");
        list.add("dd");
        new Test().doOtherStuff();
    }

    public void doOtherStuff() {
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

So same way, remove your list declaration from `main` & put it outside main, & then access list from `main` as well as from `doOtherStufff()` in static way.

Comment: So this allows you to use the Arraylist anywhere in the class Test then?  without having to like return it seperate

Comment: yes, that is correct @LukasvanDee , because you declared it as class level static member variable. Class level member variable can be accessed from anywhere within class & that don't need return from any specific method; only changes would be how you can access those.